# changing and hiding Volume HUD(the overlay of volume) while play music library in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, volume, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer` to control to play internal music.

```
extension MPVolumeView {
    var volumeSlider: UISlider? {
        showsRouteButton = false
        showsVolumeSlider = false
        isHidden = true
        for subview in subviews where subview is UISlider {
            let slider =  subview as! UISlider
            slider.isContinuous = false
            slider.value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
            return slider
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer
player.shuffleMode = .off
player.setQueue(with: MPMediaItemCollection(items: [mediaItem]))
player.play()

let volView = MPVolumeView()
view.addSubview(volView)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(volView, at: 0)
volView.frame.origin.x = -1000

/* I also tried:
MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)
MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: -1000, y: -1000, width: 0, height: 0))
none of them works.
*/

// get the slider to change to volume
let slider = volView.volumeSlider!

// set the volume. when I change, the volume HUD appears. but I want to stop appearing.
slider.setValue(1, animated: false)
```

I want to know when changing the volume, how can I stop the volume HUD popping up?

EDITED.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

System Volume is user experience 
any way you can use this

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(MPVolumeView(), at: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that digging around in the MPVolumeView this way is completely unsupported, and there is no promise that it will work in future versions of iOS. Apple intentionally does not provide a way to change the master volume. It is exactly the kind of thing that may be moved into a separate process in the future. Apple has been moving a lot of these kinds of things into separate processes.

(I say all this because I'm in the same boat with a product that does about the same thing, and I've been working for over a year to devise a new solution that does not require modifying the volume. You don't want to do this unless it is critical to the product.)

To your actual question, move the view off-screen:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
    let volView = MPVolumeView()
    volView.frame = CGRect(x: -window.frame.size.width,
                           y: -window.frame.size.height, 
                           width: window.frame.size.width,
                           height: window.frame.size.height)
    window.addSubview(volView)
}
```

Comment: I trid setting CGRact.zero and other CGPoint. It doesn’t work. So I asked here.

Comment: @abdelahad is right that you ned to add the view to the window.

Comment: still not work. I modified the code and add the link of code.

Comment: Forgot that the default frame is `CGRectZero`, which won't work. Updated with a frame that is known to be large enough (the whole screen)

Comment: hey, I tried your updated code. still doesn't work. why did I specify iOS 11. because I think in iOS 11, apple changed something to insist the volume HUD on the screen. therefore, your code doesn't work that doesn't surprise me.